# How do I implement category selection in Django? Help me. teachers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm a student learning Django. I'm trying to make a shopping mall, but I'm having a hard time registering the product. When a member registers a product himself, I would like to select the category designated in the database and register the product. My current code is this, how can I select a category as a drop-down and register it? Great developers, I'd really appreciate your help.

+I tried other methods, but the form is not applicable. Is there any other way than to designate category_code as Choice Field in the form? I'd like to implement a category selection using the drop-down.

**model.py**

```
# 카테고리
class Category(models.Model):
    category_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, allow_unicode=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering =['category_code']
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('zeronine:product_in_category', args=[self.slug])

# 상품
class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='username')
    category_code = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=False, allow_unicode=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    benefit = models.TextField()
    detail = models.TextField()
    target_price = models.IntegerField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    due_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['product_code']
        index_together = [['product_code', 'slug']]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('zeronine:product_detail', args=[self.product_code, self.slug])
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from zeronine.models import *
from .forms import ProductForm

# Create your views here.

def product_upload(request):
    current_category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    slug = Product.slug

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            product = Product()
            product.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            product.benefit = form.cleaned_data['benefit']
            product.detail = form.cleaned_data['detail']
            product.target_price = form.cleaned_data['target_price']
            product.start_date = form.cleaned_data['start_date']
            product.due_date = form.cleaned_data['due_date']
            product.category_code = form.cleaned_data['category_code']
            product.image = request.FILES['image']
            product.username = request.user
            product.slug = slug
            product.save()
            return render(request, 'zeronine/list.html',
                          {'form': form, 'current_category': current_category, 'categories': categories, 'slug': slug})

    else:
        form = ProductForm()

    return render(request, 'product/product_upload.html', {'form': form, 'current_category': current_category, 'categories': categories})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (
        (11, '교내용품'),
        (12, '패션잡화'),
        (13, '생활용품'),
        (21, '식품'),
    )
    name = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': "상품명을 입력하세요."}, max_length=32, label="상품명")
    category = forms.CheckboxInput()
    benefit = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': "공동구매 취지를 입력해주세요."}, label="공동구매 취지", widget=forms.Textarea)
    detail = forms.CharField(error_messages={'required': "상품 설명을 입력하세요"}, label="상품 설명")
    target_price = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={'required': "목표 금액을 입력하세요."}, label="목표금액")
    start_date = forms.DateField(error_messages={'required': "모집 시작일을 선택해주세요."}, label="모집 시작일")
    due_date = forms.DateField(error_messages={'required': "모집 마감일을 선택해주세요."}, label="모집 마감일")
    image = forms.ImageField(error_messages={'required': "사진을 첨부해주세요."}, label="상품 이미지")
    category = forms.ChoiceField(error_messages={'required': "사진을 첨부해주세요."}, label="카테고리", choices=CHOICES)
```

**product_upload.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container my-4">
    <h3 style="margin-top:40px; margin-bottom: -15px; text-align: center"><b>상품 등록</b></h3>
    <div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-12">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'zeronine:product_upload' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}"><b>{{ field.label }}</b></label>
        {% ifequal field.name 'detail' %}
        <textarea name="{{field.name}}" placeholder="상품에 대한 상세 정보를 입력해주세요." class="form-control" cols="160" rows="10"></textarea>
      {% else %}
      <br>
        <input type="{{ field.field.widget.input_type }}" class="form-control" id='{{ field.id_for_label }}' placeholder="{{ field.label }}" name='{{ field.name }}'>
      {% endifequal %}
      {% if field.errors %}
      <span>{{ field.errors }}</span>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      <button type="submit" action="{% url 'zeronine:product_upload' %}" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right; background: #637B46; border: white">등록하기</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please first remove the category field category = forms.CheckboxInput() from the model form bcoz you have added it twice.

by default, django render dropdown for foreign key

Comment: Thank you for discovering. I'll try that way. Also, I have a question, so I can get the datefield date input with the following code, but I want to modify this part to get the value input through the datepicker, how do I do this?

Comment: please reach out to this article https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html